# Free different types of dynamic 2D arrays

Tags: c

If i have two different types of dynamic arrays, for example int **A and double **B.
Can i build a one free function for both arrays, to free the memory.
Something like this

```
 void free_matrix(void **A,int row){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<row;i++)
            free(A[i]);
        free(A);
    }
```